# which locale ID does relative the charset 'iso-2022-jp'?

Tags: character-encoding, vb6

Charset 'shift_jis' relative Locale ID is '0411',
then which locale ID does relative the charset 'iso-2022-jp'?

cause i can use

```
StrConv(byte, vbUnicode, &H411)
```

in vb6 to convert byte to string (i know the byte's charset is shift_jis),
but i can't convert the byte which charset is 'iso-2022-jp' to string without it's local ID, thanks!

Comment: http://www.livio.net/main/charset.asp

Comment: thank IvanH to comment though i visited the document via google. i think the locale ID is a unique definition for every country/area, which means there is only one ID 'H411' for Japan, and it seems can relative charset of 'shift_jis', but how about 'iso-2022-jp'?